# YUI: Button on: click not being called when expected

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, yui3

I am trying to create a YUI 3 button that is associated with an html `<button>` with the id `#createSubAccountBtn`. The html bit is as follows:

```
<button id='createSubAccountBtn'>Create Sub Account</button>
```

And JS/YUI3 that is supposed to handle and render a YUI button for that id looks like the following:

```
    var createSubAccountBtn = new YUIRef.Button({srcNode: '#createSubAccountBtn', on: {
            'click': function(){
                alert("Made it to YUI button definition");
                newSubAccountClicked();
            }
        }}).render();
```

I don't really understand why the alert I wrote is not being executed after I click the corresponding `<button>` tag in my document.

Comment: in case you were wondering I have tried clearing my cache and checking the browser's console for any js error but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the YUI code was in a different scope than that of the `<button>` and hence why it wasn't responding!